# C++: Issue reading decimal with dot (not coma) in XML

Tags: c++, xml, qt, setlocale

I'm making a program in Qt 4.8.5 on a fedora system using C++. The thing is that I have some information on a XML (whose format I can't change) and I have a value on it like that:

```
 ValueA="0.30000"
```

The XML is correct and the reading too so don't worry about it. The thing is: to read it, I use a function of a library made by a mate (in C++ too) and here is the problem. As you see the separator is a dot (not a coma) and it has to be this way but... if I read it in my OS with Qt and a dot, what I get is a`0` value while if I put a coma (0,30000) what I get is `30` (the funcion returns you only the right part if the left one is 0).

I already had this problem with another program I had to do before with the same value and the solution was putting the next line into the main.cpp:

`setlocale(LC_ALL,"C");`

And it worked!! But now... doing exactly the same thing (or at least that is what I think because something have to have changed) it doesn't work. I've tried too removing the setlocale() function but the behaviour of the program is the same with and without that line: I get the 30 with a coma and a 0 with the dot.

And yes, everytime I change something like that I run qmake, clean the  project and rebuild it.

Any idea of what am I missing or doing wrong or how can I achive getting the 30 value with the dot in the xml? Changing the setlocale of the library, the Qt version or something in the XML is not an option because it is working this way in the hardware for the other apps (but not mine).

Thank you so much!

Note: I don't see why are you voting to close the topic. I'm not asking why it doesn't work... I'm asking about how to read the xml with a dot and not a coma wich it has to do nothing with a debugging problem in my opinion

Comment: I don't think this is really related, but are your forced to use Qt 4.8.5? Why don't you use the latest version?
I didn't understand what you want to achieve:  do you want to parse the number `0.30000` or do you want to split into `0` and `30`?

Comment: @Michael also switching to latest versin is not an option. I have the 0.3000 value, the library reads it and returns it to me but it just reads it correctly if it has a coma (returns a 30) and bad if it has a dot (returns 0 as default value). I can't change any of the things mentioned because it is working this way for other apps (but not mine)

Comment: Why don't you just write `30` then? If you want it to be read as `30` I don't understand why you write `0.30000`.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to be debugging how your library function is parsing the value string. This doesn't seem to be an xml nor a qt question.

Comment: @Michael because, as I already said I CAN'T change it. It is working now for other programs and I can't make the behaviour only for mine

Comment: Could you provide more information about how you translate the number from the file to a double? Are you using streams, Qt, another library?

Comment: As @acraig5075 said, this is an error related to your library. Study the sources, debug it, and try to add here the code.

Comment: @acraig5075 yes, I see it but what I don't understand is why does it work for every program of my enterprise except with mine... and why does setlocale() do nothing right now... it's the same if I put it than if I don't ...

Comment: @Megasa3 check your code against others' code. Perhaps you missed something needed by that library.

Comment: @Megasa3 What if you put setlocale(...) just before you read the value? It might be that it is reset in another part of the program, this happened to me before. If the library you're using is based on standard streams, `imbue` could be a very good alternative as well

Comment: ok let me check all that guys :)

Comment: From the info given, presuming there's nothing wrong with the setup of your Qt libraries, I'd suggest taking input as QString (if you aren't already) and then use the replace member function like myStrVal.replace(',', '.');
Then use toDouble or toFloat to convert to the appropriate floating point variable and then take it from there.

Comment: O man. You did completely wrong and you asking a wrong question. Why you do this manually instead use [DOM](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/xml-dom-tml.html) or [SAX](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/xml-sax.html) xml parser? Reading and searching documentation is one of most important skill of every software developer.

Comment: I would recommend to use code like this in the conversion string to float: bool ok;
double d;

QLocale c(QLocale::C);
d = c.toDouble( "1234.56", &ok );  // ok == true, d == 1234.56
QLocale german(QLocale::German);
d = german.toDouble( "1234,56", &ok );